# remove duplicated rows and keep those with specific pattern in another column

Tags: r

I would like to remove duplicated rows based on column "miRNA2", and for the duplicated rows I would like to keep the rows that has `3p` or `5p` in column "miRNA".

What I am workin on:

```
df[ !duplicated(df$miRNA2), ]
```

In

```
   miRNA miRNA2
1     -1     -1
2  -1-3p     -1
3  -1-5p     -1
4    -10    -10
5 -10-3p    -10
6 -10-5p    -10
```

out

```
   miRNA miRNA2
2  -1-3p     -1
3  -1-5p     -1
5 -10-3p    -10
6 -10-5p    -10
```

Comment: Hi, what happens if for example on some miRNA2 there are only miRNA's with only intergers?

Comment: `subset(df,!which(duplicated(miRNA2)|duplicated(miRNA2, fromLast = TRUE))%in%grep("(3|5)p",miRNA,invert = TRUE))`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this can work on most cases, I added a couple of edge cases in your example just in case you have either a just numeric miRNA (-5,-5) or a truly duplicated case (-10-5p -10)

```r
library(tidyverse)


df_example <- data.table::fread("miRNA miRNA2
   -1     -1
-1-3p     -1
-1-5p     -1
-5        -5
  -10    -10
-10-3p    -10
-10-5p    -10
-10-5p    -10") %>% tibble()

df_example
#> # A tibble: 8 x 2
#>   miRNA  miRNA2
#>   <chr>   <int>
#> 1 -1         -1
#> 2 -1-3p      -1
#> 3 -1-5p      -1
#> 4 -5         -5
#> 5 -10       -10
#> 6 -10-3p    -10
#> 7 -10-5p    -10
#> 8 -10-5p    -10


df_example %>%
  group_by(miRNA2) %>%
  mutate(unique_row = n_distinct(miRNA)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(unique_row == 1 | str_detect(miRNA, "3p|5p")) %>%
  select(-unique_row) %>%
  distinct()
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   miRNA  miRNA2
#>   <chr>   <int>
#> 1 -1-3p      -1
#> 2 -1-5p      -1
#> 3 -5         -5
#> 4 -10-3p    -10
#> 5 -10-5p    -10
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"tbl_df"’

Comment: Have you used library(tidyverse)?

Comment: If that still doesn't solve the issue maybe you have some conflicting packages, in that case try `dplyr::select`

Comment: In that case, try to discover what is the conflicting package with dplyr, but if this answer solved your question please consider up-voting and accepting as the answer